# Exact meaning of "Generation Uphill"

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is a "Generation Uphill" article about the millenials from [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/sites/default/files/special-reports-pdfs/20160123_the_young.pdf). I've looked up in some dictionaries for uphill word, however I am not sure is it used here as an adverb or an adjective.

So what is the exact meaning of "Generation Uphill" in this context?

Comment: It means that the current generation, also known as Millenials, who are just now coming of age, have an *uphill battle* in front of them. As in the status quo (in terms of economy, market structure, political parties in power, and so on) is such that the effort required for them to become successful is meaningfully greater than it was for previous generations to achieve similar levels of success. The common example given is student loan debt, the negative balance one has to pay off before accruing capital for his own purposes, is much greater than in the past. And so on.

Comment: The metaphor is that it's much harder to *defend* the top of a hill, during a battle or military conflict, than it is to prosecute or attack going the other way, i.e. uphill. Hence the related phrase "seek high ground".

Comment: @Dan Bron Your comment would qualify as an answer.

Comment: @ab2 The trouble with answers is they have to be justified. Now, I believe I am right, but proving it is more effort that I'm willing to put in. That said, you (or anyone else) is more than welcome to post an answer based on my comments, or just quoting them verbatim if you feel no need to justify them. You don't even need to mention my name.

Comment: @ab2 I've added an answer, do me a favor and review it, particularly the banner I placed at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in [my](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314812/exact-meaning-of-generation-uphill/314816#comment713774_314812) [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314812/exact-meaning-of-generation-uphill/314816#comment713773_314812), "uphill" comes from the martial metaphor, "*uphill battle*".

The metaphor is that it's much easier to defend the top of a hill, during a battle or military conflict, and much harder to prosecute or attack going the other way, i.e. uphill. Hence the related phrase "*seek high ground*".

Thus, as an extension of the metaphor, and in combination with the by-now stock term "Generation <Whatever>" (as in Generation X, Generation Y, etc), "Generation Uphill" means that the current generation, also known as Millenials, who are just now coming of age, have an uphill battle in front of them.

As in the status quo (in terms of economy, market structure, political parties in power, and so on) is such that the effort required for them to become successful is meaningfully greater than it was for previous generations to achieve similar levels of success. The common example given is student loan debt, the negative balance one has to pay off before accruing capital for his own purposes, is much greater than in the past. And so on.

Whether or not you find this label or argument convincing is another question worthy of another debate, but that's what's being implied by the label.

Comment: I've never met anyone on SE as cool as you Dan Bron. :) Can't vote (Limit)

Comment: @NVZ Haha, thanks. But you have to cast your vote! Comments or answers? You must decide! I just get "*Please convert [that comment] to an answer*" a lot on SE, and that injunction reads to me like "*Do me a solid and put in a bunch of extra work, or post an answer which will be penalized for insufficient justification*". I've found it frustrating recently. Hence this experiment, though I know the methodology is imperfect, and results will be skewed by random uninvolved users voting on the merit of the answer proper, by the fact that comments only take 3 flags to delete, and so on.

Comment: **Commenting** is your superpower. It's what made you my favourite bloke on SE.

Comment: I voted up for this particular comment-converted-to-an-answer.  That doesn't mean that I think all of your comments are worthy of being converted. HOWEVER: you did not answer the specific adverb or adjective question the OP asked.  You really should!

Comment: @ab2 The point is to test whether people, when they suggest I turn my comment into an answer, are actually happy with the results when I post them as-is (and I agree not all my comments should be answers, but I'm using this as a test-case for when someone specifically prompts me to do this). That is, to just copy/paste the comment, unmodified -- and, critically, with *no extra effort* -- as an answer proper. Of course I could always *actually* answer (with all the effort entailed), but we know that, so I'm trying to figure out what people mean when they suggest I turn my comments into answers.

Comment: @ab2 For example, here, you're right, I could address the further question of adverbs vs adjectives; I could include a formal definition, with citations, of "uphill battle"; I could talk about the origins of the construction "Generation Whatever", with further examples, to demonstrate, rather than just assert, it's being used as a snowclone. Heck. I could have at least *read* the Economist article to at least validate my assumptions about what it's saying (I didn't)! So when people say "that comment should be an answer", I want to see what that really means.

Comment: @DanBron What I understand from "that comment should be an answer" is that it "is *verrrry* close to an answer, but don't post it as is."

Comment: @NVZ My take has always been it's either to be interpreted as "literally post that as-is, don't answer in the comments!" or "you have the right of it there, why not take some time and effort and build it into an answer". I figured this quantitative experiment can help us suss out which option, among yours, and those two, and others, people prefer.

Comment: I'd go for option 3 but prefer not to add an answer at this time as "Generation Uphill" is new to me and I haven't done the research needed for a proper answer. I think option 3 is also most consistent with SE's *repository of expert answers* philosophy, though it's subjective how extensive substantiation must be.

Comment: @Lawrence "Not having done the research for a proper answer" is precisely the motivation for comment-answering, and getting people to realize what they're asking of me when they suggest that I "turn my comment into a proper answer" is precisely the motivation behind my inclusion of option #3 here: I turn the question around and say *you're free to do so; you have my unqualified blessing to post your own proper answer based on my comment*. Doing this makes them think about what *they'd* have to do (research) to answer properly. They start seeing from my perspective, so they stop scolding me.

Comment: @Lawrence And your comment is a perfect case in point. You commented *because you didn't want to go through all the effort of actually answering, even though you think that's the right thing to do, and even believe doing so is the action most consistent with SE's foundational philosophy*. In other words: my sneaky trick worked out just as I planned, heh heh heh.

Comment: @DanBron Ok, I fell for it :P . I don't think I've ever scolded you for it, though; I'd go further and commend you on your generosity. I think comment-answers fill a niche as you describe, particularly for partial answers and not quite fully-expressed intuitions.

Comment: @Lawrence No, you've always been really enthusiastic and civil around here. I don't think I've ever seen you scold *anyone*. If I could +1 you for being a good dude, I would.

Comment: I respect what you are trying to do here. I would prefer it if you posted your experimental guidelines on Meta and linked to that question rather than including it at the head of your answer. That way, community members can offer more discussion and I don't have to try to figure out how to prune the commentary.